# Estimating joint interaction with emmeans() and emtrends() for continuous variable

Tags: interaction, emmeans

I am tryying the estimate the joint interaction for continuous variables with the  `emmeans::emtrends()` function but I am having trouble doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated it. See example below

```r
library("tibble")
n=1e4
simdata <- tibble(
  age = rnorm(n, mean=30, sd=2),
  bmi = rnorm(n, mean=22, sd=2),
  age_c = age - mean(age),
  bmi_c = bmi - mean(bmi),
  y = rnorm(n, mean=2 + 2*age_c + 3*bmi_c + 4*age_c*bmi_c, sd=2)
)
model_y <- glm(y~age_c*bmi_c, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data=simdata)
summary(model_y)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ age_c * bmi_c, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), 
#>     data = simdata)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
#> -7.773  -1.382   0.014   1.365   7.950  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 1.990902   0.020204   98.54   <2e-16 ***
#> age_c       1.999852   0.010100  198.00   <2e-16 ***
#> bmi_c       3.000901   0.009994  300.27   <2e-16 ***
#> age_c:bmi_c 4.003130   0.005000  800.55   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 4.08059)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 3217872  on 9999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:   40790  on 9996  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 42447
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2


library("emmeans")
#mean difference in y for 1 unit increase in age_c across levels of bmi_c
(beta_age_c_bmi_c0 = 2) 
#> [1] 2
(beta_age_c_bmi_c1 = 2 + 3.99)
#> [1] 5.99
emmeans::emtrends(model_y, 
         specs = "bmi_c",
         var = "age_c", 
         at = list(bmi_c= c(0, 1)))
#>  bmi_c age_c.trend      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>      0       2.000 0.01010 9996    1.980    2.020
#>      1       6.003 0.01112 9996    5.981    6.025
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

#mean difference in y for 1 unit increase in bmi_c across levels of age_c
(beta_bmi_c_age_c0 = 3)
#> [1] 3
(beta_bmi_c_age_c1 = 3 + 3.99)
#> [1] 6.99
emmeans::emtrends(model_y, 
         specs = "age_c",
         var = "bmi_c", 
         at = list(age_c= c(0, 1)))
#>  age_c bmi_c.trend       SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
#>      0       3.001 0.009994 9996    2.981    3.020
#>      1       7.004 0.011227 9996    6.982    7.026
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

I want to get the mean difference in y for 1-unit increase in age_c AND 1-unit increase in bmi_c.
I would like to obtain it using `emtrends()` but I am not sure what the command is. I am trying to get the output below

```r
(beta_bmi_c1_age_c1 = 3 + 2 + 3.99)
#> [1] 8.99
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "joint interaction", but from the bottom line of your question it appears you just want the difference between estimates at (1,1) and (0,0) where the coordinates refer to `(age_c, bmi_c)`. One way (of many) to get this is

```
emm <- emmeans(model_y, ~ age_c * bmi_c, at = list(age_c = 0:1, bmi_c = 0:1))
emm
contrast (emm, list(est = c(-1, 0, 0, 1)))
```

Your example is not reproducible since you don't set the seed. So my results differ somewhat:

```
> emm
 age_c bmi_c emmean      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
     0     0  2.031 0.02004 9996    1.991    2.070
     1     0  4.042 0.02241 9996    3.998    4.086
     0     1  5.044 0.02236 9996    5.001    5.088
     1     1 11.052 0.02502 9996   11.003   11.101

Confidence level used: 0.95 

> contrast (emm, list(est = c(-1, 0, 0, 1)))
 contrast estimate      SE   df t.ratio p.value
 est         9.021 0.01501 9996 600.895  <.0001
```

#### Doing it using `emtrends()`

You can do the same thing using `emtrends()` by combining two slopes, keeping track of the starting points:

```
> (age_c.tr <- emtrends(model_y, "bmi_c", var = "age_c", 
+                       at = list(bmi_c = 0)))
 bmi_c age_c.trend   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
     0        2.01 0.01 9996     1.99     2.03

Confidence level used: 0.95 

> (bmi_c.tr <- emtrends(model_y, "age_c", var = "bmi_c", 
+                       at = list(age_c = 1)))
 age_c bmi_c.trend      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
     1        7.01 0.01124 9996    6.988    7.032

Confidence level used: 0.95 

> # Now sum these two results
> contrast(rbind(age_c.tr, bmi_c.tr), list(comb.trend = c(1, 1)))
 contrast   estimate      SE   df t.ratio p.value
 comb.trend    9.021 0.01501 9996 600.895  <.0001
```

... but I think the first way is simpler and less prone to hazards

Comment: Thank you @Russ. Could you explain what the `contrast (emm, list(est = c(-1, 0, 0, 1)))` does. Not sure what the -1 and 0 represent. Also thought there would be an easier more straighforwward way of getting the estimate using `emtrends()`. Thanks again

Comment: It means -1 times the first mean. plus 0 times the 2nd, plus 0 times the 3rd, plus 1 times the 4th.